# rethinkdb and eqJoin

Tags: php, rethinkdb

I have two tables. on the left side i have a secondary index called `tour_id` matching the `id` on the right side. My `eqJoin` request works just fine and will give me in a loop all the joined tables

```
r\table('left')->eqJoin('tour_id', r\table('right'))->zip()->run($conn);
```

But I can't figure how to retrieve a join for one particular `id`. `eqJoin` is supposed to be like `getAll`, but if I replace `tour_id` with an actual `id` i just have a blank result. I'm using php-rql and can't find any clue about the right way to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to do this:

```
r\table('left')->getAll(left_id)->eqJoin('tour_id', r\table('right'))
```

Or perhaps something like this:

```
r\table('left')->filter({'tour_id' => right_id})->eqJoin('tour_id', r\table('right'))
```

`eqJoin` and `getAll` different operations:

- `getAll` retrieves documents by an exact match on an indexed value.
- `eqJoin` is sugar for a `map` on one table that does a `get` on another table.